# How to derive the "well-known" solution to Unconstrained Array Gain?

Tags: adaptive-filters, beamforming, optimal-filter

Can someone point me to a webpage or other resource that shows how to analytically solve the beamformer Unconstrained Array Gain expression in Henry Cox's 1987 IEEE paper "Robust Adaptive Beamforming"?

$$ \max_{\mathbf{w}} \frac{|\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}|^2}{\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}} $$

Cox says:

> The well-known solution is $\mathbf{w} = \alpha\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}$

I'd just like to better understand this by learning how to derive this myself.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but perhaps they calculated the derivative of the expression and validated where the derivative equals 0.

Comment: The solution of this **equality constrained quadratic programming** problem is possible that uses a **pseudoinverse**, rather than simple inverse, of matrix Q. For general equality constrained QP problems, this extended solution has a benefit of relaxing the requirement for matrix Q to be **strictly positive definite**. Don't know if this generalization may be useful for beamformers.

Answer (score 5):

A common way is to make use of the [Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). First note that:

$$\frac{|w^Hd|^2}{w^HQw} = \frac{|w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d|^2}{w^HQw}$$

Using the Schwarz inequality on the numerator: $$\frac{|w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d|^2}{w^HQw} \leq \frac{(w^HQw)(d^HQ^{-1}d)}{w^HQw} = d^HQ^{-1}d$$

Thus, $$\frac{|w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d|^2}{w^HQw} \leq d^HQ^{-1}d$$

From this, it can easily be seen that the beamformer that achieves equality is $w = \alpha Q^{-1}d$.

Sources:

- Introduction to Adaptive Arrays, by Monzingo & Miller
- [L.E. Brennan and I.S. Read, "Theory of adaptive radar," *IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems*, Vol. AES-9, March 1973, pp. 237-252](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4103115)

Comment: To show that this $w$ maximizes SNR, simply substitute $w = Q^{-1}d$ into the inequality above. First, expand the numerator of the left side of the inequality, noting that $Q$ is Hermitian: 

$$\frac{|w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d|^2}{w^HQw} = \frac{(w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d)^H(w^HQ^{1/2}Q^{-1/2}d)}{w^HQw} = \frac{d^Hww^Hd}{w^HQw} $$ 

Then, substituting $w = Q^{-1}d$: $$ \frac{d^Hww^Hd}{w^HQw} = \frac{d^HQ^{-1}dd^HQ^{-1}d}{d^HQ^{-1}QQ^{-1}d} = \frac{d^HQ^{-1}dd^HQ^{-1}d}{d^HQ^{-1}d} = d^HQ^{-1}d $$ 

Thus, this definition of $w$ achieves the maximum possible SNR indicated by the Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve such a problem using the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). First note that maximizing the expression in your question is equivalent to minimizing the inverse function:

$$\min_{\mathbf{w}}\frac{\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}}{|\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}|^2}\tag{1}$$

Next note that the solution of $(1)$ is invariant to scaling of $\mathbf{w}$, i.e., replacing $\mathbf{w}$ by $c\cdot\mathbf{w}$ in $(1)$ with an arbitrary scalar constant $c$ will not change the value of the function. So we may as well use a scaling such that $\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}=1$ is satisfied. This scaling corresponds to a unity response for the desired signal. With this constraint, problem $(1)$ can be reformulated as

$$\min_{\mathbf{w}}\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}\qquad\textrm{s.t.}\qquad \mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}=1\tag{2}$$

We can solve $(2)$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers by minimizing

$$\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}-\lambda(\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}-1)\tag{3}$$

Formally taking the derivative of $(3)$ with respect to $\mathbf{w}^H$ and setting it to zero gives

$$\mathbf{w}=\lambda\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}\tag{4}$$

The constraint in $(2)$ is satisfied for

$$\lambda=\frac{1}{\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}}\tag{5}$$

From $(4)$ and $(5)$ we finally obtain

$$\mathbf{w}=\frac{\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}}{\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}}\tag{6}$$

Note that the scaling in $(6)$ is optional and the general solution is given by $(4)$.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are a great trick! Years ago, I **had** always thought they were a little sketchy, but I've used them to solve several constrained optimization problems. And they work well.

Comment: "Formally taking the derivative of (3) with respect of $w^H$": do you suggest that the Lagrangian (3) is the function of three independent variables, $w, w^H,$ and $λ$? If so, you can likewise take the derivative with respect to $w$ and, setting it to zero, arrive at another minimization equation $w^HQ=0$, can't you?

Comment: @V.V.T: No, this wouldn't make sense, but I understand that the version I used also looks like it didn't make sense ... This is related to the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives). Please take a look at [this related answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51249/4298), and the other answer on math.SE that it links to.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with "intricacies" of complex differentiation. Struggling to connect the derivation of formula for MOE beamformer weights and the equality constrained QP problems (like, e.g., in https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-20-sl15.pdf, Def. / Prop. 18.3), I wonder if a factor 1/2 in definition of a real quadratic form matrix (page #821, or 3/39) may be offset for complex-valued matrices rightly as manifestation of these intricacies. Would you please comment on relevance of this explanation?

Comment: @V.V.T: Maybe it would be a good idea to formulate this as a full question, either here or maybe even better on math.SE.

Answer (score 2):

First, a sketch of the solution for the maximum SINR beamformer problem
$$
\text{max}_{\mathbf{w}} \frac{|\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}|^2}{\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}}
$$
Start with writing down a functional
$$
\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}
$$
to be minimized, and **a set of constraints**. Indeed, the weight vectors **w** and **w**<sup>H</sup> are considered the two independent set of variables when taking derivates with respect to these variables; therefore, the output signal energy, typically written as a squared modulus of the weights-signals coproduct, has to be written down as an analytic function, without computing the norm that takes the square root:
$$
|\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}|^2 = \mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}·\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{w}
$$
The resulting set of linear constraints is
$$
\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d} = c \\
\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{w} = c^*
$$
and we have to write down a Lagrangian with two Lagrange multipliers, λ and μ:
$$
\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{w}-λ(\mathbf{w}^H\mathbf{d}-c)-μ(\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{w}-c^*)
$$
Taking the two derivatives of the Lagrangian -- the first, with respect to **w**, and the second, with respect to **w**<sup>H</sup> -- we obtain the expressions for **λ** and **μ**, and, substituting these to the constraint expressions, finally arrive at the formula for weights:
$$
\mathbf{w}=c\frac{\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}}{\mathbf{d}^H\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{d}}
$$
To my surprize, searching a web for "a webpage or other resource that shows how to analytically solve the beamformer" per OP's request, I could find only curtailed, flawed versions of this formula's derivation, a typical document being [the course notes Optimal Beamforming](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/%7Ersadve/Notes/BeamForming.pdf), a detailed and useful introduction into the subject in all the other aspects. I even suspect that the OP posted the question with the purpose to broadcast this omission of the learning resource (excuse my awkward attempt to joke).

For now, I can only recommend the learning material on **general linear constraint quadratic programming** to students interested in the optimal beamforming. For example, refs. [https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter3.pdf](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Erohop/fall_06/Chapter3.pdf) and [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-20-sl15.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis515/cis515-20-sl15.pdf) . Only real-valued quadratic forms are considered in these documents, but the main results can be generalized to the complex domain.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. Very helpful. I had no idea that  and  could be treated as independent variables. Many of the details here seem to be above my standard math background from electrical engineering.

Comment: Something else I just noticed - isn't the Gain expression required to be a real number, yet the denominator  is complex?

Comment: Oh - I just figured it out - When Q is Hermitian, the denominator does reduce to a real number. I proved this to myself both by hand with a 2x2 Q and 2x1 w, and in Octave as well.

Comment: "seem to be above my standard math background from electrical engineering": Wait, your questions on SE reveal, least to say, your intuitive sense of crucial issues arisen from application of math tools (SVD vs. Colesky, remember?).

Comment: I know a few radically-minded (and successful) engineers declaring that EE is "a branch of applied mathematics". Certainly it is not, being an autonomous discipline with a distinct field of study, uses, and tooling; but it certainly does use advanced mathematics and, in reciprocal motion, contributes to a development of math theories (e.g., see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226818/is-there-any-abstract-theory-of-electrical-networks).

Comment: "I proved this ... both by hand ... and in Octave": an efficient, although not universal, way of learning and research. "had no idea that  and  could be treated as independent variables" notice that this treatment also requires **two sets of Lagrange multipliers** in Lagrange equations, this is the gist of my answer.